# PTIJ - Mixed Drinks in the Torah

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

In Parshas Zachor (Devarim 25:18) it says:

> ויזנב בך כל
>
> All tails are within you

This would presumably include cocktails, and the Passuk teaches us that all of these can be found in the Torah (Shebichsav and Shebaal Peh).

Another proof to this is Yeshaya 51:17, where it says:

> מִיַּ֥ד יְהוָ֖ה אֶת־כּ֣וֹס... שָׁתִ֖ית מָצִֽית
>
> From God's hand (i.e. in the Torah) the cup which you ...drink from can be found.

Therefore, here's a [list of common cocktails](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cocktails). Which common cocktails (whether from that list or not) can you find mentioned or hinted to in Tanach, Talmud, or elsewhere in Jewish literature?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A8_%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%A7%D7%90_%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%A8_%D7%A7%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%90_%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%99_%D7%A8%D7%91_%D7%97%D7%A1%D7%93%D7%90 I can't remember where I saw their brothers quoted: מר טיני and מר גריתא

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is (unfortunately) one cocktail that Judaism is very definitely against. As we read in [Tehillim 9:6](https://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2609.htm):

> אִבַּדְתָּ רָשָׁע שְׁמָם מָחִיתָ
>
> You have destroyed the evil [drinks]; their name is *mojito*.

Comment: Lol.  We are also against the https://www.saq.com/page/en/saqcom/cocktail/purple-jesus-ec

Comment: @רבות Why? Because it’s impossible to check the raspberry for bugs? ;-)

Comment: that's exactly what I meant!

Comment: A *mojito* is so sweet it is wicked.  +1.

Answer (score 10):

Hashem Himself doesn't drink alcohol, and therefore He'd prefer you make for Him a (Shirley) Temple:

> ועשו לי מקדש
>
> Make for me a temple

As it says (Melachim 1 8:13),

> בנה בניתי בית זבול לך
>
> I, Shirley, built a temple for you

(H/t to DoubleAA for the second source)

Answer (score 7):

The Mishnah (14:3) and Gemara (110a) in Shabbos discuss one who drinks a [Daiquiri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daiquiri):

> אֲבָל שׁוֹתֶה הוּא **מֵי דְקָרִים** לְצִמְאוֹ
>
> But he may drink many daiquiris to quench his thirst.

Additionally, the Yerushalmi (Berachos 6:8) discusses what Beracha to make on this cocktail:

> א״ר אבון השותה מי דקרים מהו אומר...

Comment: Although the side effects discussed in Shabbat 110a sound a little worse than the hangover you’d expect to get from two or three daiquiris...

Answer (score 5):

[Ezekiel 37:8-10](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1237.htm) describes what are clearly [Zombies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_(cocktail)):

> וְרָאִיתִי וְהִנֵּה-עֲלֵיהֶם גִּדִים, וּבָשָׂר עָלָה, וַיִּקְרַם עֲלֵיהֶם עוֹר, מִלְמָעְלָה; וְרוּחַ, אֵין בָּהֶם.
>
> And I beheld, and, lo, there were sinews upon them, and flesh came up, and skin covered them above; but there was no breath in them.

Zephania 3:8 talks about a specific zombie names Kol Haron Api and Isaiah 66:14 explains how zombies will attack Israel's enemies, as discussed in [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/26253/472).

Answer (score 4):

Mai Tai is mentioned in Devarim 4:27:

...ונשארתם מתי מספר

You shall be left with a number of Mai Tai's.

So, on Purim, it seems that if one must indulge, he should have a few Mai Tais. And, you're welcome to come to my home. I make them well!

Comment: Also, G-d says that the Mai Tai is His handiwork, in which He takes pride. See Yeshaya 60:21 - מטעי מעשה ידי להתפאר.

Comment: @DanF  *groans audibly whilst stifling laughter*

Comment: @SAH Have a few Mai Tais. You'll get over it :-)

Answer (score 4):

[Death in the Afternoon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_in_the_Afternoon_(cocktail)?wprov=sfti1) is mentioned in Melachim Beis 4:20:

> וַיִּשָּׂאֵ֔הוּ וַיְבִיאֵ֖הוּ אֶל־אִמּ֑וֹ וַיֵּ֧שֶׁב עַל־בִּרְכֶּ֛יהָ עַד־הַֽצָּהֳרַ֖יִם וַיָּמֹֽת׃
>
> And they carried him and they brought him to his mother, and he laid on her lap until noon, and he died.

Now, it’s a debate whether “until” includes the number specified (עד ועד בכלל או לא עד בכלל). For instance, R’ Yehudah (Berachos 27a), Rebbi (Erchin 18a-b), and maybe R’ Yochanan (Nazir 6b) hold that it is included, while the Chachamim (Erchin 18a-b) and maybe R’ Yoshaya (Nazir 6b) hold that it is not included.

If you hold עד ועד בכלל, then the child was unconscious until noon and died after - thus, death in the afternoon. If you hold לא עד בכלל, then the child died exactly at noon.

Now, there is some [confusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12-hour_clock#Confusion_at_noon_and_midnight) as to whether AM or PM should be used for 12 noon. Therefore, we can pose a Sefeik Sefeikah: maybe we hold עד ועד בכלל, and even if we don’t, maybe noon is considered afternoon anyway. This is even reversible: maybe noon is considered afternoon, and even if it’s not, maybe we hold עד ועד בכלל.

So at least *we* can conclude that Death in the Afternoon is mentioned in Tanach. As for those who hold עד ולא עד בכלל and that noon is AM...? אין מקשין על האגדה.

Answer (score 3):

We know that after the Mabul, Noach got drunk (Bereishis 9:21).  What cocktail did he drink?

Likely, he had just finished disassembling the Teivah with his [screwdriver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screwdriver_(cocktail))...

Answer (score 3):

Shlomo HaMelech discusses the effects of drinking [the last word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Last_Word_(cocktail)) (Koheles 12:13):

> סוף דבר הכל נשמע
>
> The last word - everything is heard

Similar to the effects of drinking wine, after drinking the last word all of your secrets come out and everything is heard.

Answer (score 2):

Sforno claimed that during the 10th plague, Moshe and Aaron sipped on more than a few Red Deaths (http://allrecipes.com/recipe/80455/red-death-cocktail/) prior to digging into their lamb platters

Answer (score 2):

> השם סַלְעִי וּמְצוּדָתִי וּמְפַלְטִי קלִי צוּרִי
>
> Hashem is my rock [...] my God is my rock

([Psalms 18:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.18.3?lang=bi); very loose translation)

We see that God is referred to as multiple types of rocks, so whatever you're drinking, enjoy it [on the rocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bartending_terminology#On_the_rocks).

Answer (score 1):

The word Yisrael appears many times throughout the Torah, but most importantly, it is [the last word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Last_Word_(cocktail)) in the final Passuk in the Torah, Devarim 34:12.

Comment: Every book with words has a last word... I don't think this qualifies as hinted to in the Torah. Although I'm about to post my own reference to this beverage.

Comment: @Yez Ya, I'm maskim it was a bit of a dumb one...